# Parsing a complex JSON GET CALL USING ORACLE JSON_TABLE

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex, json-value

I have a following GET call response.

```json
{
  "PrepaymentIncludedonInvoiceFlag": null,
  "ReferenceKeyTwo": null,
  "ProductTable": null,
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "domain.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/300000165112384/child/invoiceLines/00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001",
      "name": "invoiceLines",
      "kind": "item",
      "properties": {
        "changeIndicator": "ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A65787000000001770400000001737200116A6176612E6C616E672E496E746567657212E2A0A4F781873802000149000576616C7565787200106A6176612E6C616E672E4E756D62657286AC951D0B94E08B02000078700000000278"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Out of the above GET response, I only need to parse the highlighted string shown below and store it into a CLOB.

href": "fa-esgu-dev5-domain.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/300000165112384/child/invoiceLines/**00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001**

How can I achieve this using Oracle JSON_TABLE or any other Oracle centric method?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JSON_TABLE but JSON_VALUE for this. As per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html):

*The SQL/JSON function JSON_VALUE finds a specified scalar JSON value in JSON data and returns it as a SQL value.*

Once you know that, it's actually quite simple:

Select `JSON_VALUE(json_data,'$.links[0].href')`, where (1) `$` is the JSON context, (2) `links[0]` is the first element of the "links" array and (3) `href` is the scalar value of the href attribute in the selected links element.

```
with json_doc AS 
(SELECT
'{
  "PrepaymentIncludedonInvoiceFlag": null,
  "ReferenceKeyTwo": null,
  "ProductTable": null,
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "domain.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/300000165112384/child/invoiceLines/00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001",
      "name": "invoiceLines",
      "kind": "item",
      "properties": {
        "changeIndicator": "ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A65787000000001770400000001737200116A6176612E6C616E672E496E746567657212E2A0A4F781873802000149000576616C7565787200106A6176612E6C616E672E4E756D62657286AC951D0B94E08B02000078700000000278"
      }
    }
  ]
}' AS json_data FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  JSON_VALUE(json_data,'$.links[0].href')
from json_doc WHERE json_data IS JSON;

JSON_VALUE(JSON_DATA,'$.LINKS[0].HREF')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
domain.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/300000165112384/child/invoiceLines/00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001
```

The "href" attribute seems to be a rest source so I'm assuming that the value you need is the string after the last forward slash. Here is how to get the only that value:

```
with json_doc AS 
(SELECT
'{
  "PrepaymentIncludedonInvoiceFlag": null,
  "ReferenceKeyTwo": null,
  "ProductTable": null,
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "domain.com/fscmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/invoices/300000165112384/child/invoiceLines/00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001",
      "name": "invoiceLines",
      "kind": "item",
      "properties": {
        "changeIndicator": "ACED0005737200136A6176612E7574696C2E41727261794C6973747881D21D99C7619D03000149000473697A65787000000001770400000001737200116A6176612E6C616E672E496E746567657212E2A0A4F781873802000149000576616C7565787200106A6176612E6C616E672E4E756D62657286AC951D0B94E08B02000078700000000278"
      }
    }
  ]
}' AS json_data FROM dual
)
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(JSON_VALUE(json_data,'$.links[0].href'),INSTR(JSON_VALUE(json_data,'$.links[0].href'),'/',-1) + 1) as val
from json_doc WHERE json_data IS JSON;

VAL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------
00020000000EACED00057708000110D93B462A400000000AACED0005770400000001
```

Comment: Thank you Koen. But I only need to extract part of the href value highlighted in bold in the OP.

Comment: Well... what are the rules for that highlighted value ? Pls specify exactly how to look for it. It looks like it's always after the 8th forward slash. Will that always be the case ? Is that the only requirement ?  Have you tried anything yourself (getting an nth occurence in a string is a pretty common question...) and what errors did you get ?

Comment: That is the issue, there is no consistent pattern here. I reached out to vendor with this issue and they confirmed that this can only be resolved with a java program.  Which is an overkill for me.

Comment: see my updated answer on how (probably) you'll always get that last value